# Using Node.js / Express is it possible to next() an error from inside an IIFE and advance to the error handling middleware?

Tags: express, error-handling, iife

**Question:** Using Express is it possible to return an error from inside an IIFE and advance to my error handling middleware?
**Background:** The [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is used to create an [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) container to wrap [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) statements.  I can't see a way out of this and I wonder if I'm using the wrong basic, pattern altogether.

**Simplified Example:**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    (async function() {

        try {
            let example = await someLogic(x);
        } catch(err) {
            return next(new Error('oops'));
        } 
    })();

    console.log('main endpoint');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

    console.log('my error', err.message);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using Express is it possible to return an error from inside an IIFE and advance to my error handling middleware?

Yes, that works fine.  It will call `next(err)` just fine.  But, your `return` will return only from the IIFE and the rest of your request handler after the `try/catch` will still execute (not sure if you want that or not).

---

FYI, it's probably simpler to declare the request handler as `async` and then you don't need the IIFE wrapper:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {

    try {
        let example = await someLogic(x);

        console.log('main endpoint');
        // send some response here

    } catch(err) {
        return next(new Error('oops'));
    } 
});
```

Comment: Awesome!  My real route is 50 lines or so.  Would it be ok to wrap the entire route in a single try / catch or is that practice frowned upon?

Comment: @myNewAccount - It's fine to wrap the whole thing if that's the granularity that you want to catch it with.